# ANSIBLE set tags per item in with_items loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, configuration-management, ansible-playbook

I have this playbook to create ec2 instances and will like to target each ec2 creation by tags but not working...when i run playbook i do not get any errors but notting gets created.

```
---
- name: Build or Check environment
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - ../vars/kafka-east.yml

  tasks:

    # name: launch kafka-east-1 ec2 instance
    - ec2:
       image: "{{ ami_id }}"
       key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
       instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
       instance_profile_name: "{{ instance_profile_name }}"
       region: us-east-1
       network_interfaces: "{{ item.eni }}"
       with_items:
          - {eni: 'kafka_east_1', tag: 'kafka_east_1'}
          - {eni: 'kafka_east_2', tag: 'kafka_east_2'}
       volumes:
       - device_name: /dev/sda1
         volume_size: "{{ ebs_size }}"
         device_type: "{{ ebs_type }}"
         delete_on_termination: true
       user_data: "{{ lookup('file', '../group_vars/kafka-east/user_data') }}"
       state: present
```

i get errors but just posted to kind of show what i am trying to accomplish. Anyone know how to properly achieve that? and set tags for each item in the with_items and loop round

so i can run the playbook and target a specific tag like this

```
ansible-playbook launch_ec2.yml --extra-vars "items_tags=kafka_east_1"
```

OR

```
ansible-playbook launch_ec2.yml --tags "kafka_east_1"
```

whichever way is correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First: The correct syntax for the `with_items` loop is:

```
- name: task name
  module:
    parameter1: value1
    parameter2: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - item1
    - item2
```

So thats wrong and I wonder why Ansible didn't trow an error.

Second: You are mixing up `tags in AWS` with `tags in Ansible`. `Tags in AWS` are used to tag resources in AWS and the Ansible AWS modules usually feature this via parameters. But that's different from `tags in Ansible`. Those are used to tag tasks in a playbook to be able to limit the tasks executed by `ansible-playbook` to a subset of the tasks in a play.

tag a task in Ansible like this:

```
- name: task name
  module:
    parameter1: value1
  tags:
    - tag1
    - tag2
```

You could than limit the tasks executed by `ansible-playbook` like this:

```
ansible-playbook --tags=tag1 play.yml
```

Comment: mm not so  clear..why not  use my example code and replace with what is correct? that will be greatly  appreciated..i will understand it better that way

Comment: Yeah, but the idea behind ServerFault is actually more about giving answers that could help more than one person and less about giving you a copy&paste ready code snippet enabling you to deploy systems you can't manage. Your mistakes are trivial and seem to me caused by using a software without consulting the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_module.html) which is something I consider not professional.

Comment: i think you going too far there...there are many solutions to an answer or route to solve a problem..also i posted a problem and you writing solution to another problem..makes no sense..anyways thanks..will move on to another answer or search elsewhere..if something is not clear i will say its not clear..if you cant explain it any further other than saying other things then good day

Comment: @HenrikPingel "*I wonder why Ansible didn't trow an error.*" -- why do you think it should throw an error with the code given in the question?

Comment: Because the `with_items` task loop is at the wrong position and has a wrong indention. At least nothing in the documentation I know of indicates that this could be correct.

Comment: @HenrikPingel It's not correct semantically, but nothing stops you from adding `blabla: true` as a parameter to any module and Ansible has no grounds to complain.